# Vector with undefined size as Class member

Tags: c++, class, vector

I am trying to create a class with a vector with undefined size as class member. My code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Polynom.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Polynom p {{7,-2,3,0,0,8}};
    return 0;
}
```

**Polynom.h**

```
#ifndef INC_0001_POLYNOM_H
#define INC_0001_POLYNOM_H

#include "Polynom.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Polynom {
private:
    vector<int> vec;
public:
    Polynom(vector<int> vec);
};


#endif //INC_0001_POLYNOM_H
```

**Polynom.cpp**

```
#include "Polynom.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

Polynom::Polynom(vector<int> vec){
    this->vec=vec;
}
```

But whenever i try to run this code i get following error,

```
main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `Polynom::Polynom(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)'
```

The code was longer initially but I had way too many errors when i tried to run it. So I tried to run the bare bone...

PS:I am trying to create a class where i have to input for example 7,-2,3,0,0,8 then couts 8x^5+0x^4+0x^3+3x^2+-2x^1+7x^0 (with a method), but it is undefined how many numbers i type in.

Edit: I use CLion and the CMakeList is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(0001)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(0001 ${SOURCE_FILES})

MinGW version 5.0
Bundled CMake 3.7.2
Bundled GDB 7.11.1
```

[What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Isnt helpful because I am relative new to C++ and on that thread it is writen so complicated that I dont understand anything (and dont even how it related to my problem beside the error message)

**And there is another Problem according to the CLion there is a parameter type mismatch (At `Polynom p {{7,-2,3,0,0,8}};`). Which means that there should be other problems.**

How do i adjust my constructor so it can build a class this way `Polynom p {{7,-2,3,0,0,8}};`

Comment: The problem is with how you are building the code.  What exact build steps are you running?  You're somehow not linking in `Polynom.cpp`.

Comment: How do I link in Polynom.cpp? I am trying to create a class where i have to input for example 7,-2,3,0,0,8 then couts 8x^5+0x^4+0x^3+3x^2+-2x^1+7x^0

Comment: Polynom.h need not #include "Polynom.h"

Comment: Originally it didnt have #include "Polynom.h"... but when i was trying to solve the problem I tried everything possible (even though many things I did didnt have practical uses)

Comment: I think the code is 'good-enough' to compile ... my version does, but I take short-cuts, did all in one file.  Perhaps you could show us your compile / build command?

Comment: Although it is stated below by li.hao `Polynom p {{7,-2,3,0,0,8}};` is a C++11 feature. So you need to make sure your compiler supports C++11

Comment: I use CLion (for students) (mingw32) (I dont use any commands i just click on run button on the top right corner)

Comment: What exact build steps are you running?  What is your build configuration?  What compilation commands are you running?  Without this information no solution can be found.

Comment: i use cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(0001)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(0001 ${SOURCE_FILES})

Which mean i use C++14

Comment: I use     
    MinGW version 5.0
    Bundled CMake 3.7.2
    Bundled GDB 7.11.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the code below to the link options:

`g++ main.cpp polynom.cpp -std=c++0x`

I tried this method to solve your problem.

Comment: OK, in CLion u have to add the file into the CMakeLists if it didnt added it when it create the file for example: set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Smoothie.cpp Smoothie.h Zutat.cpp Zutat.h)
add_executable(CLion ${SOURCE_FILES} Smoothie.cpp Smoothie.h Zutat.cpp Zutat.h)